# Angular2 date conversion into quarter

Tags: datetime, angular, highcharts

I am trying to create an XAxis data for HighCharts showing quarters in format:
Dec2016, Mar2017, Jun2017.
As input I get a date from DB in format:  2014-12-15T00:00:00.000Z
and a list of months shifts: 0, 3, 6, 9,...

Can someone suggest how to do that conversion?
I was thinking maybe of Moment and Pipes,
but am new to it all, need a guidance.

So far even importing Moment into Angular2 produces errors, it can't see moment module in:
import {MomentModule} from 'angular2-moment/moment.module';   // d.ts and js is there

Please help!

TIA,
Oleg.

Comment: The question is not clear for me. See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981453/get-current-quarter-in-year-with-javascript) how you can convert date to quarter. You can see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543896/highcharts-time-based-quarterly-data-xaxis-label-issue) how you can set tick intervals to be quarterly.

Comment: I was able to do it with standard Moment (without Angular2 specific), seems to work fine in Ang2 2.0