# How change time frame in hc_xAxis - month in quartal

Tags: r, highcharts

I wants plot time series in HighCharts where time frame is quarter. But on X-axis I have only monthly. How convert month on quarter data? I find answer on my question in this post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543896/highcharts-time-based-quarterly-data-xaxis-label-issue) but I don't know how realisation this in R.

```
xAxis: {
        alternateGridColor: '#FAFAFA',
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '9px',
                width: '175px'
            },
            formatter: function () {
                var s;
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Jan') {
                    s = s + "Q1"
                };
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Apr') {
                    s = s + "Q2"
                };
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Jul') {
                    s = s + "Q3"
                };
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Oct') {
                    s = s + "Q4"
                };
                s = s + " " + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value);
                return s;
            }
        },
        tickInterval: 31536000000,
        type: 'datetime'
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
library("lubridate") # 
library("readxl")
library("zoo") #
library("xts") #
library("dplyr") # 
library("ggplot2") # 
library("gridExtra") # Multiplot
library("forecast")
library("tseries") #для Arima
library("TTR") # SMA
library("fUnitRoots") #tests for stationarity
library("xlsx")
library("RODBC") # xls Excel <- odbcConnectExcel
library("Quandl")
library("highcharter")
library("quantmod")
library("XLConnect")
library("xlsx")
library("js") #Tools for Working with JavaScript in R

# load data
tmpgdplev = tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
download.file(url = "https://www.bea.gov/national/xls/gdplev.xlsx", destfile = tmpgdplev, mode="wb")
mydatagdplev<-read.xlsx(tmpgdplev, 1, startRow = 6)

RealGDPQ<-ts(removeNA(mydatagdplev[1:nrow(mydatagdplev),6]), frequency=4, start=c(1947,1))

prirost<-function(x)
{
  d<-diff(x)
  res<-NULL
  for(i in 1:length(d)) 
  {res<-append(res, d[i]/x[i])}
  return(res)
}

dRGDP<-prirost(RealGDP)

dRGDPQ<-prirost(RealGDPQ)
round(dRGDP,4)
round(dRGDPQ*100,2)

prirostQ<-function(x)
{
  d<-diff(x,lag = 4)
  res<-NULL
  for(i in 1:length(d)) 
  {res<-append(res, d[i]/x[i])}
  return(res)
}

dRGDPQ2<-prirostQ(RealGDPQ)
round(dRGDPQ2*100,2)

dQRGDPQ<-(dRGDPQ+1)^4-1
round(dQRGDPQ*100,2)

k<-NULL
for(i in 1:NROW(removeNA(mydatagdplev[ ,1]))) 
{k<-append(k, as.character(mydatagdplev[i,1]))}
dpc<-years(k)
n<-NA
n1<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA)

QRealGDPtable<-data.frame(Qdate, RealGDPQ, round(append(n,dRGDPQ)*100,2 ), round(append( n1,dRGDPQ2)*100,2 ), round(append(n,dQRGDPQ)*100,2 ))
colnames(QRealGDPtable)<-c("date", "QRealGDP", "Growth","QQGrowth", "annualGrowthRate")
Qdate<-as.yearqtr(1947 + seq(0, nrow(mydatagdplev)-1)/4)
#### This my working time siries
QQRGDPts<-ts(QRealGDPtable$QQGrowth, start=c(1947,1), frequency=4)

QQRGDP <- highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Q U.S. GDP ") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text = "Source: U.S. Bureau of Economic Analysis",  align = "left") %>%
  hc_add_series(QQRGDPts, type="column")
  QQRGDP
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue comes in trying to show quarterly data cleanly on the xAxis. I understand what I must use functions formatter and tickInterval in hc_xAxis() and maybe correctly used datetime_to_timestamp()(I used ts(frequency=4) - this function doesn't work in highcharter{}). In above post this problem was solved in javascript but I don't know how realisation this in R.